# ListenSocket ClientSocket Go

Tags: go

In **[this article](https://github.com/astaxie/build-web-application-with-golang/blob/master/en/03.3.md)** about `Go Web Server`, there're `Listen Socket` and `Client Socket` in `Go`,

I can't understand why GoLang need two sockets `Listen Socket, Client Socket` but not just one socket, can anyone explain its concept or give a metaphor?

[image]

**EDIT :** I update my answer.

Comment: That's just trying to show how TCP connections are handled, it's not specific to go at all. The server has to accept the client connection, otherwise it does nothing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<del>Maybe I misunderstanding the graph or the graph isn't draw very well, possibly `Listen Socket`, `Client Socket` are same socket, if the socket hasn't accept connection from client, it's called `Listen Socket`, and after it accept the connection, it's renamed to `Client Socket`, there's only one socket with different stage and name.</del>

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I find a better article and graph about Socket Working **[Here](https://www.micrium.com/setting-up-a-socket-in-uctcp-ip-part-2/)**.

In the grpah of article, it's clear when there's new connection, TCP Server will
create a new socket to handle the connection, and the `Listen Socket` continuing listening for other connections.

Here's a paragraph in the article:

> The first socket created by a TCP server, via `NetSock_Open()`, is typically designated a `listen socket` , and, after the call to `NetSock_Listen()`, remains open indefinitely, to allow the server to respond to various connection requests. Rather than using this socket to exchange data with requesting clients, the server will create a new socket for each request.

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2**

Since first update is working on Micrium, I find another seems more general TCP working instuction **[Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.9/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.09/gtps5/s5tcpcf.html)**:

> TCP connection flow The following sequence shows the flow of a TCP

> connection:

> 1. The server creates the listener socket that is waiting for remote clients to connect.

> 2. The client issues the connect() socket function to start the TCP handshake (SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK). The server issues the accept() socket
>    function to accept the connection request.

> 3. The client and server issue the read() and write() socket functions to exchange data over the socket.

> Note: There are several SSL APIs that you can use to send and receive data other than the read() and write() socket functions.

> 4. Either the server or the client decides to close the socket. This causes the TCP closure sequence (FINs and ACKs) to occur.

> 5. The server either closes the listener socket or repeats beginning with step 2 to accept another connection from a remote client.

> **Note: Normally after the accept() socket function ends, the server divides
> into two processes (or threads). The first process handles the
> connection with the client and the second process issues the next
> accept() socket function. Figure 1 shows an example of a TCP
> connection:**

> [image]

Note:

1. I find another **[Socker Programming Tutorial](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/%7Ehy556/material/tutorials/cs556-3rd-tutorial.pdf)** mention about working detail in TCP.
2. And In **[.NET Framework MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.accept(v=vs.110).aspx)**, the explanation about `Socket.Accept Method()` says `Accept synchronously extracts the first pending connection request from the connection request queue of the listening socket, and then creates and returns a new Socket.`
3. I have skimmed **[RFC about TCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793)** before Update 1, but I didn't see it mention the detail that Listen use one socket, and when Accept it'll create another new Socket.
4. Maybe the  thorough way is to research the Source Code about Create Socket  and Connection in `Go`, but I'm not consiedring to do it now.

Comment: No, there are 2 sockets, the listening socket and the connected socket. From the accept(2) man page: `"[accept] extracts the first connection request on the queue of pending connections for the listening socket, sockfd, creates a new connected socket"`. It is a completely separate socket with new FD; but this isn't unique to Go, it's how TCP sockets work.

Comment: Are you really using a micrium real-time OS? I mean the general concept is the same for TCP, but these syscalls are unique to that OS.

Comment: I didn't aware that it's specific OS when reading, and I find another seems more general instruction about TCP in Update2.

Comment: You seem to be able to find the most obscure sources, that one is from IBM zSeries z/TPF. I mean, this is mostly generic information, but you should know that these sources may have details specific to their domain.